# How to use Google visualization API to retrieve google spreadsheet cell value?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm trying to get the value of a cell on a google spreadsheet but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<html>
```

```
    <script>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(loadChart);

    function loadChart() {

            var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sA7M5kG6Xo8YScD1Df38PIA_G0bvhGRdqoExXg0KJTs/edit#gid=0');

            query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

    var datatable = response.getDataTable();
    var result = datatable.getValue(0,0);

    document.getElementById('output1').value = result;
    document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = result;
    document.getElementById('output3').textContent = result.toString();
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    Test 1: There are <input id="output1"> value <br>

    Test 2: There are <p id="output2"> value </p> 

    <p> Test 3: There are <a id="output3"> </a> value </p>

</body>
```

The Spreadsheet url [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sA7M5kG6Xo8YScD1Df38PIA_G0bvhGRdqoExXg0KJTs/edit#gid=0)

Comment: do you receive an error? does this help? --> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sA7M5kG6Xo8YScD1Df38PIA_G0bvhGRdqoExXg0KJTs/gviz/tq?headers=1&tq=SELECT A`

Comment: Hi, yes. I get  "Error in query: Request timed out." Also tried using the link you provided and its the same error.

Comment: comment from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35457016/5090771) -- _the query was just timing out because some of the returned JSON code included some null data points_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onpageshow = function () {
            google.load('visualization', '1', {
                callback: function () {
                    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sA7M5kG6Xo8YScD1Df38PIA_G0bvhGRdqoExXg0KJTs/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq?gid=0&headers=0&range=A1:C');
                    query.send(displayData);
                }
            });

            function displayData(response) {
                numval = response.getDataTable().getValue(0,0);
                document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = numval;
            }
        }
    </script>  
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <div id="data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```